# Find optimal filter of combination of attributes in pandas dataframe to maximise value column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, combinations, python-itertools

My end goal is to find what combination of attributes maximises value.
My plan is to first create a list of all possible combination of key value pairs and then iterate overt it, assigning the corresponding value for each attribute combination and then sorting it to find the best combo. I'd like to find the most efficient method to do this.

The mock dataframe can be built as such:

```
brand = ['Ford', 'Fiat', 'Mercedes', 'Ford']
color = ['Red', 'Red' , 'Green', 'Blue']
model = ['Berline', 'Berline', 'Berline', 'truck']
engine_size = [2.0, 1.8, 1.5, 3.5]
made_in = ['Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe']
value = [100,250,60,80]
data = pd.DataFrame({'brand': brand, 'color': color, 'model': model, 'engine_size':engine_size, 'made_in': made_in, 'value':value})
```

I drop columns that only have one value:

```
cols_to_drop = [i for i in data.columns if len(set(data[i]))==1]
data.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Alll possible column combinations looks like this:

```
[('brand',),
 ('color',),
 ('engine_size',),
 ('model',),
 ('brand', 'color'),
 ('brand', 'engine_size'),
 ('brand', 'model'),
 ('color', 'engine_size'),
 ('color', 'model'),
 ('engine_size', 'model'),
 ('brand', 'color', 'engine_size'),
 ('brand', 'color', 'model'),
 ('brand', 'engine_size', 'model'),
 ('color', 'engine_size', 'model')]
```

I found the above list using itertools:

```
import itertools
combos = []
for length in range(0, len(data)):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(data, length):
        combos.append(subset)
```

I need to find a way to make a single list which finds all possible column:value combinations nested within all these column combinations.

If we take the ('brand', 'model'), line for example, then it should end up looking like this:

```
[{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Berline'}, {'brand':'Fiat', 'model':'Berline'}, {'brand':'Mercedes', 'model: 'Berline'}, {'brand':'Ford', 'model':'truck'}, {'brand':'Fiat', 'model':'truck'}, {'brand': 'Mercede', 'model':'truck'}]
```

And I want this for every line and then flattened out so it will be a single list of dictionaries. Then I can iterate over every dictionary filtering out the df at each iteration and summing the value. Then, finally I will sort and find the optimal combination to maximise value.

This is obviously not a very efficient method because many of those combos don't exist (eg Fiat Truck), but I can't think of anything else...Open to any other suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a new key for `merge`

```
data['key']=1
data[['brand','key']].merge(data[['model','key']]).drop_duplicates().drop('key',1).to_dict('r')

Out[1000]: 
[{'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'Berline'},
 {'brand': 'Ford', 'model': 'truck'},
 {'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'Berline'},
 {'brand': 'Fiat', 'model': 'truck'},
 {'brand': 'Mercedes', 'model': 'Berline'},
 {'brand': 'Mercedes', 'model': 'truck'}]
```